# How to use inner join on Subquery() Dajngo ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class FirstModel(models.Model():
    some_fields...

class SecondModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.IntegerField()
    first_model = models.ForeignKey(to="FirstModel", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and I need to do the following query:

```
select sum(value) from second_model

inner join (
   select max(date) as max_date, id from second_model
   where date < NOW()
   group by id
) as subquery
on date = max_date and id = subquery.id
```

I think I can do it using [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

```
subquery = Subquery(SecondModel.objects.values("first_model")
            .annotate(max_date=Max("date"))
            .filter(date__lt=Func(function="NOW")))
```

and [F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) but it only can resolve model fields, not a subquery

Question

Is it possible to implement using Django ORM only?

Also, can I evaluate the sum of values from the second model for all values in the first model by annotating this value? Like

```
FirstModel.objects.annotate(sum_values=sum_with_inner_join_query).all()
```